# Comparing file names in driectory with database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm currently looping through files in a directory to see if any file names from a particular directory match listed file names in a database.  I am doing this as follows:

```
Dir.foreach("#{path}/#{directory}") do |file|
            puts "File name is #{file}"
            puts "true if in database: #{@company.assets.where(uploaded_file_file_name: file).exists?}"
end
```

The issue is that when I added all the file names to the database for a sanity check, `exists?` kept coming up false.

However, if I store any of the names as a variable and check `exists?`, it comes up true.  I just can't get it to work off of `|file|` in the loop above.  I should note that `puts #{file}` simply displays the file name, leading me to believe that `file` is just a simple string.  Is there something special about `Dir` that would cause this?  Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the issue.  Paperclip was replacing any whitespace with underscores, so most of the entries had one or two underscores which I'd overlooked.  I just had to do the same to `file` in the loop:

```
filesnake=file.tr(" ", "_").tr(",", "_")
```

And then compare `filesnake` instead of `file`

```
@company.assets.exists?(uploaded_file_file_name: filesnake)
```

Answer (score 1):

`Dir.foreach` iterates over filename including the path. I guess you just stored the filename (without the path) into your database.

Please try:

```
@company.assets.exists?(
  uploaded_file_file_name: File.basename(file)
)
```

Comment: And, if that works, the OP should strongly consider redoing the code so that path is signficant. Only looking at the filename negates the advantages to having paths on the filesystem.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response.  Unfortunately I found that the error was a blunder on my part.  Paperclip had replaced any whitespace with underscores, which I had overlooked.  Ultimately I did not find, however, that I needed to specify `File.basename(file)` in order to simply get the file name.  Thanks anyway!